# Unable to start systemd container using Docker (CentOS 7.8 Host). Failed to mount API filesystems, freezing

Tags: docker, centos7, systemd

I am trying to run a container with systemd but I keep getting the following error -

```
Failed to mount tmpfs at /run: Operation not permitted
Failed to mount cgroup at /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd: Operation not permitted
[!!!!!!] Failed to mount API filesystems, freezing.
```

I have read the Official documentation of [CentOS on Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos). Accordingly I have made the dockerfile as follows(recommended by CentOS documentation on Dockerhub).

```
FROM centos:7.8.2003
ENV container docker
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == \
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;
STOPSIGNAL SIGRTMIN+3
VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

Also after reading the [blog](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/09/13/running-systemd-in-a-non-privileged-container/) of Daniel Walsh on RedHat, I installed the OCI hooks hoping that they would solve the problem.

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -qa | grep oci
oci-systemd-hook-0.2.0-1.git05e6923.el7_6.x86_64
oci-register-machine-0-6.git2b44233.el7.x86_64
```

However when I start the container using the command `docker run --name="OS-level-try" -it 2_os_image` ,  I get the aforementioned error of "Failed to mount API filesystem". But if I try running the container with SystemAdmin capabilities it runs smoothly. Like this - `docker run --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --name="OS-level" -d --rm 2_os_image`

**Question-1** If I have to use SYS_ADMIN capibilities to run the container, then what is the use of OCI hooks? They seem to be quiet redundant.

**Question-2** How can I run the container without giving out SYS_ADMIN capabilities to the container?

PS- 2_os_image is the docker image built from the aforementioned dockerfile.

Comment: In general I'd try to avoid running systemd in Docker.  Just run the single process you need to run in the foreground as the main container process.  If you really need systemd for some reason, running it in a VM will virtualize all of the things it wants to control.

Comment: I got your point @DavidMaze that Docker should be used to run single services only. But in my case, I am trying to emulate a developer workspace inside a container that will have services like postgres, php, java, etc running in it. That's why I need systemd to run properly inside container.

Comment: That sounds like a virtual machine setup; Vagrant is a popular tool for setting up a developer-oriented VM.  Or you can use Docker Compose to set up several interconnected single-process containers.